# solidworks to urdf

Tags: urdf, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

What I want to do is converting Solidworks assembly to urdf file. I am using sw_urdf_exporter in inidgo. The problem I have right now is the coordinates of each link are not at the correct position. Since there is no way to specify link coordinate during property manager, I wonder whether there is a way to choose coordinate for each link except manually changing coordinate values in link property after exported.
Or should I be careful about something during configuration such that coordinates of links will be correct.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286407/solidworks-to-urdf/) by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-03-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-03-24**:
@oh233 when you design create a referance coordinate fram at base of your robot and then chose that while configure the base link and in other link chose Automatically configured then you can get the right solution

**Comment by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on 2018-03-24**:
@lagankapoor I followed the way you suggested me, but the problem is all joints it automatically detected are fixed. I wonder whether coordinate system belongs to joint during configuration of each links. I want to manaully define all coordinate systems. Thanks for your reply.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-03-27**:
@Oh233 sorry for late reply , you then select joint specific . i mean which is revolute and which is prismatic . i done this way and select link very carefully . if you have screenshot share with me for more understanding

**Comment by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on 2018-03-27**:
@lagankapoor Thank you so much for your reply. I think my problem has been solved. I first chose automatically generate for every link, and then went back to choose the coordinate I built for base link in configuration. It worked.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-03-28**:
yeah So post Answer and mark it Answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically the solution should be let it automatically generate the configuration after setup the whole mates. And then manually choose the coordinate you set for base_link and let the rest to be the same as before.

---

Originally posted by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) with karma: 55 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1